# How to trigger multiple gnome-terminal windows automatically and keep them open and active?

Tags: bash, tabs, tcl, interactive, gnome-terminal

the related part of the code is:

## main code

```
#.....some code

send "flag1\r"
exec gnome-terminal -t "tab1" -x bash "$HOME_PATH/scripts/startTask1.tcl"
send "flag2\r"
exec gnome-terminal -t "tab2" -x bash "$HOME_PATH/scripts/startTask2.tcl"

#.....some code
```

## startTask1.tcl

```
#.....some code
expect "flag for task2 to go"
send "flag3\r"
interact
send "flag4\r"

#.....some code
```

then i found, i can see the prints of flag1 and flag3, the window "tabl" is opened, but the tab2 could not be triggered.

I tried to closed the tabl windows, then tab2 was opened. However, what i want is to keep those 2 windows open both automatically.

My understanding is: "interact" give out the control, then the next terminal should be opened automatically, right?

I'm freshman on this, so some words above may be not exact. Very appreciate for the reply, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Brian and Donal, the issue is resolved by update the Ubuntu OS. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the outer program is waiting for the `gnome-terminal` process to finish before going on to the next step. It finishes when the subordinate process (expect I guess?) finishes.

You can run both at the same time by putting a `&` as a separate argument at the end of the `exec`:

```
exec gnome-terminal -t "tab1" -x bash "$HOME_PATH/scripts/startTask1.tcl" &
```

However, you won't be able to get the two tasks to collaborate with each other easily this way, as they are using separate virtual terminals under the covers. In fact, there'll be one virtual terminal for each `gnome-terminal` and another one (at least) for each `expect`.

I think you need to take a few steps back and work out what you really want to do. There probably are ways to do it, but they might need a different approach to the one you're currently using which looks like it is doomed to failure.

Comment: Thanks Donal,  

Actually there is one "expect" before the "interact" in the code of "startTask1.tcl", i have updated my question to make it clear.<br/>

>The requirement for the scripts is:

>1.Run the task1, wait(by expect) until some pre-condition info is printed in Task1 terminal, then give out the control by "interact";

>2.Run the task2

3.After the pre-condition info in Task1 terminal, then Task1 and Task2 could run separately, without any collaboration between them;

>How could I make it?

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but I believe the program called terminator is the only tabbed shell that uses multiple shells simultaneously. Be forewarned though, the order of calls may look simultaneous but in reality they are going to go in and out of memory in an order that can place things in userspace, kernelspace, or swapspace, at intervals that parse according to the scripting order.